# Use recovery service vault across subscriptions

Tags: azure, subscription, recovery

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is a way to use a Recovery Service Vault from another subscription to backup a VM.

Simplified it is about having only one backup service for VMs which is then used for all VMs from other subscriptions. (Keyword: consolidation of services)

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: @mslot Sorry for the late answer i dont got a notifaction for this comment. I found no answer of this question but azure service grew fast so maybe today i could be possible.